# Resolving Metadata via ArtifactResolutionService

Tags: spring-security, saml, opensaml

I am attempting to implement SAML login using Spring Security 5.5.3. Unfortunately, the metadata file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<EntityDescriptor entityID="https://remoteloginsite.org/sso/authentication"
                  xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <IDPSSODescriptor WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <ArtifactResolutionService index="0" isDefault="true" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"
                                   Location="https://remoteloginsite.org/sso/ArtifactResolver/metaAlias/authentication"/>
    </IDPSSODescriptor>
</EntityDescriptor>
```

Unfortunately, Spring Security's SAML support bombs when attempting to read this metadata file with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.security.saml2.Saml2Exception: Metadata response is missing verification certificates, necessary for verifying SAML assertions
```

I'm assuming that this simply means that 5.5.3 doesn't support resolving items such as `<SingleLogoutService>`,`<SingleLoginService>`, etc, so if I want to do it, I'll have to reach out to the `location` URL specified by the `<ArtifactResolutionService>` myself and use the results to manually build a `RelyingPartyRegistration` myself.

Question 1: Am I correct in the assumptions I've made about the steps I have to take?

Question 2: Does OpenSaml (version 3) provide any shortcuts that would make this any easier?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the version of Spring Security we used, 5.5.3, was too NEW to support artifact resolution. SAML support in Spring Security is a work in progress. We ended up not being able to use the 5.6.x releases of Spring Security because the `Saml2AuthenticationToken` did not implement the `Serializable` interface.

We manged to configure a `RelyingPartyRegistration` manually to make the first call to the IdP. Unfortunately, the response contained a SAML artifact ID, requiring us to make a second call. The IDP also turned around and made a GET request to us, which the SAML Authentication Processing Filter did not recognize.

So, we ended up creating a new implementation of the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` specifically to accept URI of that callback. We leveraged the SOAP functionality of OpenSAML 3 to manually create an `ArtifactResolve` object and sent it via SOAP to the Artifact Resolution Service URL. We received back an `ArtifactResponse` object, which we manually processed for the information we needed, then passed that into an `AuthenticationProvider` to correctly tie the whole thing into the Spring Security lifecycle.

I can't really provide much of our code, but I hope this explanation helps someone in the future.